# Finite sum of reciprocals of odd integers in terms of digamma function

Tags: summation, digamma-function

I was reading some of my old notebooks and I came across an (according to me) astounding formula:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}=\frac{\psi(n+\frac{1}{2})+\gamma}{2}+\log 2$$
I almost never gave proofs then. I tried to prove this. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) article tells us that
$$\psi(n+\frac{1}{2})=-\gamma-2\log 2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{2k-1}$$
So this is where it came from. But I don't know how to prove the latter formula. Please try to prove it for me. I may give updates that shall help to prove this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Induction. ${}$

Comment: Specifically, use Gauss's digamma theorem to obtain $\psi (1/2)$, then use the recurrence $\psi (x+1) = \psi(x) + 1/x$.

Comment: If you know the formula $$\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right),$$ then the proof is straightforward. (You will also need $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=\log 2$.)

Comment: Alternatively, apply the formula $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^z}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=H_z=\gamma+\psi(z+1)$ to \begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\log 2+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-u^{n-1/2}}{1-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\end{align*} where $u=x^2$.

Comment: @sangchullee: thanks for your hints